# ItemUpdated List Item Comparison

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject, event-receiver

Is it possible to compare the properties listItemId with a field in a new list? I have an event receiver, I want to update a new list once an item in updated. I don't want to use GetItemById, I want to compare the first list auto generated ID with a field in the new list.

```js
foreach(ListItem UpdateItem in destListItems) {
  if (properties.ListItem["ID"] == UpdateItem["NewId"]); {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

The script does not update the item in the destination list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (properties.ListItem["ID"].ToString() == UpdateItem["NewId"].ToString()); {
    UpdateItem["Field"]="123";
    UpdateItem.Update();
}
```